# How to create Win7 bootable usb from within Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, usb, wine

I know this has been asked before but the majority of the answers given seem to be a bit out of date.

I've tried the gnome disk utility, after reading somewhere in here that it might be as simple as that, I've tried running Rufus through Wine, and I've also tried Unetbootin, which actually got me so far as to boot from my pendrive, but then I got a "Missing Operating System" message flicking on my monitor from top to bottom.

Has anybody actually tested creating a Windows 7 bootable USB from within Ubuntu 16.04. And if so, how do I do it?

Comment: @DavidFoerster asked 3 years ago, that is. I did actually try winusb first, but I ran into some issues there too, till I read somewhere (can't find the link at the moment) that this utility might be a bit out of date... So then I tried other alternatives... Just wondering if anybody has actually done this in 16.04

Comment: Ah ok, can you please clarify which of the solutions mentioned in the linked question you tried? For instance https://askubuntu.com/a/487970/175814 looks promising and was recently confirmed to work by a commentator.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is dd from terminal

```
sudo dd if=location of Windows image of=/dev/sd#
```

Replace # with your usb drive letter, do not enter the partition number, then press enter. MAKE SURE to unmount the usb prior to running dd. When it runs it will look like nothings happening, when it completes it will output how much data was written. Reboot and boot from the usb.

You can run

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

To list your drives

Comment: @ ILOVEKODI That's more or less how I created my Ubuntu live USB from within a Mac. Yesterday I tried creating a Windows bootable USB the same way (from the Mac), but after plugging the drive to my pc and chaging the boot order, I got a black screen and after a while I was back in Ubuntu. Anyway, I'll give your advice a shot, running the dd command from within Ubuntu instead. Should the drive be formatted to a specific fs?

Comment: Format doesn't matter cause dd will overwrite it anyhow. Make sure all partitions are unmounted on the drive and that you are writing to the drive without a partition number inputed. Both steps are important for this to work.

Comment: For clarification it should look something like this sudo dd if=/home/admin/Windows.iso of=/dev/sdb

Comment: Yeah, I know... [Here](http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb-drive-for-pc-on-a-mac--cms-21187) 's the instructions I followed yesterday. I'll try doing the same from within Ubuntu, as you suggest. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You don't need to convert the ISO just burn it as is. That's probably what's messing it up. ALSO, leave off the bs=1m as it isn't needed

Comment: Unmounted, ran dd, waited for it to complete the job, rebooted with pendrive at the top of my boot priority, but no progress... Just for a fraction of a second I think I see a row of blue dots in the middle of a black screen, then loads Ubuntu, prompting me to provide my password. Any idea on what this could mean?

Comment: Bad iso file more than likely. Hit esc or f12 when booting and select the pen drive manually

Comment: Using the unconverted iso right?

Comment: Correct. No conversion.